# Redirect After Form Submit

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a form set up and a javascript file (as shown below) that I want to validate the input and then redirect to a different website (index.html). The validation works perfectly, but I can't figure out how to get the form to redirect to the wanted page instead of just showing the post return. The form posts to a php file (which I am unable to access), and I would like the return of that file to then be displayed on index.html.

**Form:**

```
    <form name="form" action="register.php" onsubmit="return validateInput()" method="POST" >
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Personal Details</legend>
        <label>Name</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="name"><br><br>
        <label>Email</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="email"><br><br>
        <label>Date of Birth</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="dob"><br>
      </fieldset>
      <input type="submit" name="submit"> <input type="reset" name="reset">
    </form>
```

**JavaScript File:**

```
 function validateInput() {

    var check = document.forms["form"].elements;

    for (var i = 0; i < check.length; i++) {
        var test = check[i];

        if (test.type === "text" && test.value === "") {
            displayMsg("Please fill out all fields" +test.innerHTML);
            return false;
        }
        if (test.type === "date") {
            var pattern = /^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$/;

            if (!test.value.match(pattern)) {
                displayMsg("Please enter a valid date of birth");
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if (test.name === "email") {
            var re = /^[\w\-\.\+]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]{2,4}$/;

            if (!test.value.match(re)) {
                displayMsg("Please enter a valid email address");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function displayMsg(msg) {
    var ele = document.getElementById("msg");
    ele.className = "show";
    ele.innerHTML = "<p>" + msg + "</p>";
}

window.onload = function() {
    var check = document.forms["form"].elements;
    for (var i = 0; i < check.length; i++) {
        check[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
            var ele = document.getElementById("msg");

            if(ele.className != "hide") {
                ele.className = "hide";
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: not able to find your html form. without it, how i know which function call?

Comment: @yash sorry, I'll edit with more code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `return true;` you can set the location that you want using `window.location.href` and use `return false;` to prevent the default submission of the form:

```
function validateInput() {
    ....
    window.location.href = 'index.html';
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I tried that, and it didn't work unfortunately. It still just shows me the post return from the php file.

Comment: You sure you don't have any javascript errors there? Did you check the console?

Comment: Sorry yes, was making a stupid error the whole time. Thanks, will mark as correct answer.

Comment: Do you happen to have any idea how I'd display the post return on the redirected page? I tried an ajax get function, but it isn't displaying as I'd hoped

Comment: You can use cookies/sessions for that, or maybe localStorage

Comment: I tried playing around with sessions, unsuccessfully unfortunately. Happen to have any tips..?

Comment: Without looking at your code it will be hard to understand what exactly the problem is/was, however something in the way that you do this doesn't seem right. If you are unable to access the PHP file then there is no way you can use sessions.

Comment: thats my issue, yes. I've been trying to use a separate js file, linked to a div in the html with this: 
`code`
 function displayUsername() { 
    $.get("http://turing.une.edu.au/~jbisho23/assignment2/register.php", function(data) {
        $("#username").text(data.user_id);
    });
};

$(function() {
    displayUsername();
});
`code`